# Display error on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, css, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to change the appearance to darker theme of my jupyter notebook, and have used below codes to replace three custom.css in three different folder, and my notebook now looks like this [Notebook Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK7Hm.jpg) with no top menu displaying. Please help!

Env: Anaconda 4.2.0, python 3.5
This is the instruction I referred to:
http://sherifsoliman.com/2016/01/11/theming-ipython-jupyter-notebook/

folder:

`~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\static\custom
~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\tests\dotipython_empty\profile_default\static\custom
~\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\tests\dotipython\profile_default\static`

Code:

```css
/*

    Name:       Base16 Flat Dark
    Author:     Chris Kempson (http://chriskempson.com)

    CodeMirror template adapted for IPython Notebook by Nikhil Sonnad (https://github.com/nsonnad/base16-ipython-notebook)
    CodeMirror template by Jan T. Sott (https://github.com/idleberg/base16-chrome-devtools)
    Original Base16 color scheme by Chris Kempson (https://github.com/chriskempson/base16)

*/

/* Uncomment to use a custom font
div#notebook, div.CodeMirror, div.output_area pre, div.output_wrapper, div.prompt {
  font-family: 'Custom Font Name', monospace !important;
}
*/

/* GLOBALS */
body {background-color: #2C3E50;}
a {color: #3498DB;}

/* INTRO PAGE */
.toolbar_info, .list_container {color: #f5f5f5;}

/* NOTEBOOK */

/* comment out this line to bring the toolbar back */
div#maintoolbar, div#header {display: none !important;}

div#notebook {border-top: none;}

div.input_prompt {color: #be643c;}
div.output_prompt {color: #9B59B6;}
div.input_area {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #7F8C8D;
}
div.output_area pre {font-weight: normal; color: #e0e0e0;}
div.output_subarea {font-weight: normal; color: #e0e0e0;}

.rendered_html table, .rendered_html th, .rendered_html tr, .rendered_html td {
  border: 1px  #e0e0e0 solid;
  color: #e0e0e0;
}
div.output_html { font-family: sans-serif; }
table.dataframe tr {border: 1px #e0e0e0;}

div.cell.selected {border-radius: 0px;}
div.cell.edit_mode {border-radius: 0px; border: thin solid #9B59B6;}
div.text_cell_render, div.output_html {color: #e0e0e0;}

span.ansiblack {color: #34495E;}
span.ansiblue {color: #1ABC9C;}
span.ansigray {color: #BDC3C7;}
span.ansigreen {color: #2ECC71;}
span.ansipurple {color: #9B59B6;}
span.ansired {color: #E74C3C;}
span.ansiyellow {color: #F1C40F;}

div.output_stderr {background-color: #E74C3C;}
div.output_stderr pre {color: #f5f5f5;}

.cm-s-ipython.CodeMirror {background: #2C3E50; color: #f5f5f5;}
.cm-s-ipython div.CodeMirror-selected {background: #34495E !important;}
.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-gutters {background: #2C3E50; border-right: 0px;}
.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-linenumber {color: #95A5A6;}
.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-cursor {border-left: 1px solid #BDC3C7 !important;}

.cm-s-ipython span.cm-comment {color: #be643c;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-atom {color: #9B59B6;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-number {color: #9B59B6;}

.cm-s-ipython span.cm-property, .cm-s-ipython span.cm-attribute {color: #2ECC71;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-keyword {color: #E74C3C;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-string {color: #F1C40F;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-operator {color: #be643c;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-builtin {color: #9B59B6;}

.cm-s-ipython span.cm-variable {color: #2ECC71;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-variable-2 {color: #3498DB;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-def {color: #E67E22;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-error {background: #E74C3C; color: #BDC3C7;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-bracket {color: #e0e0e0;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-tag {color: #E74C3C;}
.cm-s-ipython span.cm-link {color: #9B59B6;}

.cm-s-ipython .CodeMirror-matchingbracket { text-decoration: underline; color: #f5f5f5 !important;}
```

Comment: I've already re-installed anaconda 3 for a couple of times

Comment: can you try adding the css into the following directory `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` instead? Refresh terminal then run `jupyter notebook` where `~` is your home directory.

Comment: There is no folder `custom` under `./jupyter`. I tried to create a new `custom` folder and put `custom.css` in, nothing changed.

Comment: did you try to run the notebook in the new terminal?

Comment: That's very helpful. I opened in Edge instead of Chrome, and everything seems to be fine. But still I don't understand why chrome is working that way.

Comment: That's weird. BTW, does the CSS in `.jupyter` folder work for you now? Maybe you just need to refresh cache in Chrome.

Comment: I fixed the problem by using another python package in this github.https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes.

Comment: Just simply overwrite my errors whatever it is..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using another python package in this github.github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes